# Is it possible to use @user mentions in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app

Is it possible to use @user mentions in email composed on Mail.app? Outlook for Mac allows this and I am wondering if it is possible in Mail.app as well.

Outlook's @ mention [allows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-mentions-to-get-someone-s-attention-90701709-5dc1-41c7-aa48-b01d4a46e8c7) these:

- Lets the email composer choose a user name from the list of matching user names pulled from LDAP
- Upon choosing an entry from the dropdown, a user link is inserted into the mail body

This feature helps to draw attention of email recipients as necessary.